# Gridview not showing up on the browser in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Good Day everyone,

I have a web application that is a basic input form.  The input form has a dynamic gridview that allows users to enter any number of rows to enter trip information.

Most everything is working well except two aspects;

1. I have continued errors that say gridviewName is not in the current context
2. Finally the more important issue lies in the fact that my gridview does not appear in debug in the browser (regardless of the browser chosen).

I have researched this for a week now and I think I need a new set of eyes on this.  What could I be missing in my codebehind and aspx pages to make my gridview show up and the CodeBehind page to recognize the designer file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="intakeTripDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.TravelerInformation" %>

<asp:Content ID="intakeTripDets" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Trip Details</legend>
            <div class="input">
                <p>Please enter trip details on the below form.  You can add additional rows as needed for each leg of our trip.</p>
                <br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" Text="" ></asp:Label><br />
                <label>Flight Number(s)</label><asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br /><br /><br /><br />
                <asp:GridView ID="tripDetails" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"> 
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Arrival Date & Time" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="arrivalDateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Departure Date & Time">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="departDateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="countryList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="city" runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>   
                <div class="btnfmt"><%--<asp:Button ID="prev" runat="server" Text="Previous: Traveler Information" />--%>
                <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" text="Submit Trip"/> </div>
            </div>
       </fieldset> </asp:Content>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace travelDetails
{
    public partial class DynamicGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SetInitialRow();
            }
        }

        private ArrayList countryData()
        {
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

            arr.Add(new ListItem("Afghanistan", "1"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Aland Islands", "2"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Albania", "3"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Algeria", "4"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("American Samoa", "5"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Andorra", "6"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Angola", "7"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Anguilla", "8"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Antarctica", "9"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Antigua and Barbuda", "10"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Argentina", "11"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Armenia", "12"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Aruba", "13"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Australia", "14"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Austria", "15"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Azerbaijan", "16"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Bahamas", "17"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Bahrain", "18"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Bangladesh", "19"));
            arr.Add(new ListItem("Barbados", "20"));

            return arr;
        }

                private void FillDropDownList(DropDownList ddl)
        {
            ArrayList arr = countryData();

            foreach (ListItem item in arr)
            {
                ddl.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

            private void SetInitialRow()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr = null;

                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("arrivalDateTime", typeof(DateTime)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("departDateTime", typeof(DateTime)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("city", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("countryList", typeof(string)));

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
                dr["arrivalDateTime"] = string.Empty;
                dr["departDateTime"] = string.Empty;
                dr["city"] = string.Empty;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                //What if I want to see the data for future reference
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

                //Data is stuck here
                tripDetails.DataSource = dt;
                tripDetails.DataBind();

                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)tripDetails.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("countryList");

                FillDropDownList(ddl1);
            }

            private void AddNewRowToGrid()
            {
                int rowIndex = 0;
                if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
                {
                    DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                    DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

                    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                        drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;

                        for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {

                            //extract the textbox values
                            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)tripDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("arrivalDateTime");
                            TextBox box2 = (TextBox)tripDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("departDateTime");
                            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)tripDetails.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("city");

                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["arrivalDateTime"] = box1.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["departDateTime"] = box2.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["city"] = box3.Text;

                            //extract the ddl values
                            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)tripDetails.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("countryList");

                            //Update the DataRow with the ddl items selected
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["countryList"] = ddl1.SelectedItem.Text;
                        }

                        //Adds new row to the data table
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);

                        //Again...we probably want to refer to this again
                        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                        //Rebind the grid with the current data
                        tripDetails.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                        tripDetails.DataBind();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("View State is Null");
                    }

                    //Set previous data on postbacks
                    SetPreviousData();
                }
            }

            private void SetPreviousData()
            {
                int rowIndex = 0;
                if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)tripDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("arrivalDateTime");
                            TextBox box2 = (TextBox)tripDetails.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("departDateTime");
                            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)tripDetails.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("city");

                            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)tripDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("countryList");

                            //Fill the ddl with data
                            FillDropDownList(ddl1);

                            if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                            {
                                //Assign the value from the datatable to the textbox
                                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["arrivalDateTime"].ToString();
                                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["departDateTime"].ToString();
                                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["city"].ToString();

                                //Set the previously selected items to each ddl
                                ddl1.ClearSelection();
                                ddl1.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["countryList"].ToString()).Selected = true;
                            }
                            rowIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AddNewRowToGrid();
            }

            protected void tripDetails_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkRemove");
                    if (lb != null)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
                        {
                            if (e.Row.RowIndex == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                            {
                                lb.Visible = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lb.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            protected void lnkRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
                GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
                int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;
                if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {

                            //Remove selected row data and reset row number
                            dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);
                            ResetRowID(dt);
                        }
                    }

                    //And another future reference
                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

                    //Bind the data to the gridview again with updated data
                    tripDetails.DataSource = dt;
                    tripDetails.DataBind();
                }

                //Set previous data on postback
                SetPreviousData();
            }

            private void ResetRowID(DataTable dt)
            {
                int rowNumber = 1;
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row[0] = rowNumber;
                        rowNumber++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried everything that I can think of - 
1.  Deleting Designer file and 'Converting to Web Application'
2. Redoing the code in another file
3. Recreating the whole project
4. Making everything visible/invisible

Any help would be great!

**Edit:**
Okay update, I have made some changes and now I have errors that indicate `The type or namespace name 'DataBind' does not exist in the namespace 'tripDetails' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.  This error shows for 'DataBind' 'DataSource' and 'Rows.

What am I missing in my references or namespaces that could be causing these errors.  I did not make any changes to this area.

**Update** I was able to finally clear all the errors but I still cannot see my empty gridview in the browsers.  Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried to set variables to each of the rows you are trying to call to see if the data is being pulled through debug and break points?

Comment: A shot in the dark (to see the grid in the debugger): maybe the div should have the attribute runat="server"? I remember not seeing some tr or td elements, which had runat="server", because their table did not have that attribute.

Comment: About my previous note: I misread the description of your problem (not seeing the grid in the browser in debug, I thought "not seeing the grid in the debugger"). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused ID and Name. Name allows data to be assigned or retrieved from a control.

Change `ID="tripDetails"` `to name="tripDetails"` and it should work. Similarly, i'd then advise doing the same for the rest of the controls.

Comment: Do you mean on the aspx page?

Comment: Yes. Id's are used to identify specific items - mostly for use with things like CSS - Names are used to identify controls for functions - such as submitting forms and assigning postbacks etc

Comment: This did not work -- errors still exist that the name 'tripDetails' does not exist in the current context and the gridview is not showing up in the browser.  And now I have an parser error in the global.asax file

Comment: The problem is almost certainly to do with your asp code not connecting properly with your c# codebehind. It can't see your `tripDetails` control. Just to check, the file listed in your asp as codebehind, is that the same filename as the c# class you have written?

Comment: the reason I ask is because your namespace for your c# file is different to the one you have in the asp file. while the file name and the namespace can be different, usually the filename is used as the namespace (unless you changed it manually after file creation)

Comment: I did change it manually during my playing around but to be honest I don't remember what I had changed it from/to.  Are you saying that I need to change my namespace to intakeTravelDetails which is the name of the aspx file?

Comment: dont change the namespace as you might run into further problems. Make sure your asp `codebehind="intakeTripDetails.aspx.cs"` is pointing to the correct file - it needs to match the c# file

Comment: Okay, I took the CodeBehind  = intakeTripDetails.aspx.cs out and readded it as CodeBehind=~/intakeTripDetails.aspx.cs but now I get a variety of new errors 'The type or namespace name DataBind does not exist in the namespace 'tripDetails' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'.  I don't know what would have changed that I would be missing an assembly.  What assembly could I be missing and why would changing the codebehind cause this error?

Comment: you dont need to issue that method. you already bind the data by saying `tripDetails.Datasource = dt`

Comment: Errors still exist for 'Data Bind','DataSource' and 'Rows'.

Comment: im afraid i am at a loss for the moment. It might be worth updating your question with your most up to date attempts at solving the issue so that others might be able to move you forward.

Comment: im almost certain it was due to codebehind not linking with your asp code, which it still might not be doing properly. That said, i cant see a logical reason it suddenly started throwing out errors to do with namespaces